# QT location classes

Tags: c++, qt, location, symbian

How can I connect to gps data in qt for symbian 9.3 ?

I write this in qt

```
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
```

But result is: No such file or directory (((

I have write to .pro TARGET.CAPABILITY += Location  but it's all the same.

How i can access to location classes ?

*QT 4.7.0*

I search on my disk for, for example QGeoCoordinate class, but result is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, QGeoCoordinate is part of the [Qt Mobility API](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-addons/mobility/).

Thus, you need to install the Mobility API and add something like

```
CONFIG+=mobility
MOBILITY=location
```

to your .pro file.

Comment: #include <QtLocation/QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QtLocation/QGeoCoordinate>
#include <QtLocation/QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QtLocation/QGeoSatelliteInfo>
#include <QtLocation/QGeoSatelliteInfoSource>

Answer (score 0):

If you use Qt Creator, make sure your project is set to be built for QT Simulator or other mobile environment. It seems that the QT Creator parses the configuration and if it is set for Desktop app, fails to find the location files.

Also, make sure you have added:

using namespace QtMobility;